# convert a byte array to string at a particular index (Flex)

Tags: flex4, flash-builder

Im a bit of a newbie when it comes to Flash/Flex Builder. How do I convert a byte array to string at a particular index? I got this (b is a byte array)

```
var s:String = b.readUTFBytes(4);
```

But I need to skip to a particular point in the byte array.

In C#, I can do this which would skip the first 8 bytes.

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetString(b, 8, 4);
```

How do I do the equivalent in Flash builder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [help on ByteArrays](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=ByteArrays_2.html) has some good examples. Here is how I would do it.

```
bytes.position = 7;
trace((bytes.readUTFBytes(4)));
```